# Why is this form validation not working?

Tags: jquery, validation

```js
$("#addAlertForm").validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="addAlertForm" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
      <input type="text" name="alertText" class="form-control" maxlength="200" required>
      <label class="form-label">Alert Text</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="alertCheckbox" id="md_checkbox_10" class="chk-col-green" />
    <label for="md_checkbox_10">Alert can be dismissed</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

and it doesn't work, I press on the submit button with the field empty and no error message appears under the input telling that it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validate call should be written on `ready` like below:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#addAlertForm").validate();
});
```

Remember, this is triggered on form submit or when you press return/enter on the respective field.

Comment: Thank you alot :D